# Sum attributes from XML file

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I am having issue knowing how to sum multiple instances of the same attribute in a XML file. My first thought was to build an array to hold the values then sum them together. Unfortunately my c# code knowledge is not where it should be.

```
double customerRate = Convert.ToDouble(
    import.Elements("PriceSheets")
        .Elements("PriceSheet")
        .Where(priceSheet => priceSheet.Attribute("type").Value == "Cost" 
            && priceSheet.Attribute("isAllocated").Value == "true" 
            && priceSheet.Attribute("isSelected").Value == "true")
        .First()
        .Element("Total"));
```

Below is the XML file I read from that has the repeating attribute of Total

```
<Enterprises>    
 <PriceSheets>
    <PriceSheet type="Cost" 
        chargeModel="NORMALIZED_MANUAL" isSelected="true" isAllocated="true" 
        currencyCode="USD" createDate="05/25/2017 15:03" 
        updateDate="05/25/2017 15:18" internalId="5099262823">
    <AccessorialTotal>222.80</AccessorialTotal>
    <SubTotal>780.69</SubTotal>
    <Total>1003.49</Total>
    </PriceSheet>
 </PriceSheets>
</Enterprises>
```

Comment: Argh... my eyes...  ever heard about line breaks? ;-)

Comment: Sorry! This is my first time ever having to post on StackOverFlow so I am trying to figure out how to edit it! =)

Comment: Don't mind. I was in the process of formatting your code, but juharr was faster ;-)

Comment: How about a correct/complete Xml snippet?

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thank you! Now hopefully I get a answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy; you had most of it right:

```
var sum = 
    import
    .Elements("Enterprises")
    .Elements("PriceSheets")
    .Elements("PriceSheet")
    .Where(priceSheet => priceSheet.Attribute("type").Value == "Cost"
        && priceSheet.Attribute("isAllocated").Value == "true"
        && priceSheet.Attribute("isSelected").Value == "true")
    //  Now you're working with a sequence of all the allocated and selected "Cost" price 
    //  sheets. You got this far. 
    //  So just grab their "Total" elements...
    .Elements("Total")
    //  And sum their values. 
    .Sum(total => Convert.ToDouble(total.Value));
```